# JavaScript - Target indexes in a column of a multidimensional array below specific index

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to complete a challenge in CodeSignal's arcade that takes in a multidimensional array with integer values and adds the value of those indexes. IF an index = 0, I need to ignore that index and all indexes below that specific index. For instance:

```
array = [
[0, 1, 2],
[1, 0, 3],
[3, 1, 0]
];
```

What I am having issues with is targeting all indexes in a COLUMN starting at an index with a value of 0.  With this array I should be getting an output of 6. Here is what I have so far:

```
function matrixElementsSum(matrix) {
const checkHaunt = []; 
    for (let c = 0; c < matrix.length; c++) {
        // console.log(`Matrix: ${matrix[c]}`)
        for (let i = 0; i < matrix[c].length; i++) {
            // console.log(`index: ${matrix[c][i]}`)
            if (matrix[c][i] != 0 && c == 0) {
                checkHaunt.push(matrix[c][i]);
            }
            else if (matrix[c][i] != 0 && matrix[c-1][i] != 0) {
                checkHaunt.push(matrix[c][i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return checkHaunt.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}
```

I initially thought I needed to ignore any indexes directly below a value of 0 but I read the instructions wrong. With this code I would get an output of 9 with the above array.

Any suggestions on adding code to target the indexes I need would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your requirements correctly, I'd take a slightly different approach - keep track of columns containing zero as you encounter them; add to a sum variable otherwise:

```js
const array = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [1, 0, 3],
  [3, 1, 0]
];

function matrixElementsSum(matrix) {
  let sum = 0;
  const zeroCols = new Set();

  matrix.forEach(row => {
    row.forEach((val, i) => {
      if (val === 0) {
        zeroCols.add(i);
      } else if (!zeroCols.has(i)) {
        sum += val;
      }
    });
  });

  return sum;
}

console.log(matrixElementsSum(array));
>>> 6
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I am going to have to digest everything going on her to fully understand exactly what its doing. Thanks for the assist!